# Ending a sentence with 〜だろうが

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence while reading a character's lines, it is as follows:

> そんなの吹っ飛ばされるレンが悪いんだろうが！

My understanding of だろうが is that it means something like, "no matter what/how...", and that it's used in the middle of sentences. Is the phrase used in this sentence perhaps supposed to mean something else?

For further context, the character is saying this in response to some people badmouthing his friend.

Comment: This が is a sentence-end particle used after だろう/でしょう to to make the sentence stronger and rough. Please see the link.